# How to get the content of a row of a Numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How to get the content of a row of a Numpy array ? For example I have a Numpy array with 3 rows `color=np.array([[255,0,0],[255,255,0],[0,255,0]])` and I want to retrieve the content of the first row `[255,0,0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array indexing as below:

`color[0]`